# Create dynamic sql query depending on the search filter parameters

Tags: java, sql, spring

I'm creating search filter in my web application, and want to create dynamic sql query depending on the parameters.

I assume that parameters can have fixed value (height=100) or be in range (min_height=100&max_height=200).

Question:
What are good possibilities to do dynamic sql query? I would like to have dynamic WHERE clause.

Pseudocode:

1. in case of fixed value

```
WHERE <table>.height = searchFilter.getHeight,
```

2. in case of range

```
WHERE <table>.height BETWEEN searchFilter.getMinHeight AND searchFilter.getMaxHeight
```

I'm using jdbcTemplate from spring.

[EDIT]
What if parameters are optional e.g. **height** is set, but **width** not (then in WHERE clause **width** should be omitted)? The main question is how to do query dynamically, not how to do this specific use case.

Comment: Why not set default values for height and width and then change them if the value is supplied.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE <table>.height = searchFilter.getHeight
```

will be equivalent to

```
WHERE <table>.height between searchFilter.getHeight and searchFilter.getHeight
```

So with query

```
WHERE <table>.height between ? and ?
```

, just provide height or the range, depending on what you get.

If the parameter can be optional, just do a check before the main condition:

```
where ? is not null and ? is not null and height between ? and ?
```

or

```
where (? is not null and ? >= height) and (? is not null and ?<= height)
```

I think then the sql can be executed successfully, but then it is not a best practice because you will have implicit logic inside your query. For more dynamic query, consider to use JPA/Hibernate to implement criteria query.

Comment: Yes, also think about it, but what if some parameters are optional. Please look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `minHeight` and `maxHeight` and use:

```
WHERE <table>.height BETWEEN searchFilter.getMinHeight AND searchFilter.getMaxHeight
```

When you want a single value for `height`, set the minimum and maximum to the same value.

Comment: Yes, also think about it, but what if some parameters are optional. Please look at my edit.